# How to create meaningful route in ASP MVC 3 with Entity Framework for related Entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

Let’s say I have two entities:

Company 1 -> * User

If I want to go to the company 1, I use

http://localhost/Company/Details/1

What if I want to access the company Users?

http://localhost/Company/Details/1/Users

What if I want a pre-filled for adding users to this company?

http://localhost/Company/Details/1/Create

How can I configure those routes and rewrite them to use the User controller, with the company parameter set?

This is my best guess:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
      "CompanyUsers",
      "Company/Details/{company_id}/{action}",
      new { controller = "User", id = company_id }
    );
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you have. Did it now work?

Comment: I want to know if there is a better way, more structured way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this is what you're looking for but have you thought about utilizing [Areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793.aspx) in your application? This might give you the URL routing structure you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for showing me that, but I don’t think that’s I was looking for. How can I pass parameters to areas? For what I understand, it can be useful to group things like http://localhost/Management/Users/List, but what I want is to access the users of the said company like http://localhost/Company/Details/1/Users. I don’t if I’m clear.